# key.from_path equivalent to get_by_id in GAE datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following Model in GAE's datastore:

```
class Blog(db.Model):
    subject = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    content = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)  
    last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now = True)
```

I create a new post with the following class:

```
class NewPostHandler(Handler):
    def render_newpost(self, subject="", content="", error=""):
        self.render("newpost.html", subject=subject, content=content, error=error)

    def get(self):
        self.render_newpost()

    def post(self):
        subject = self.request.get("subject")
        content = self.request.get("content")
        if subject and content:
            a = Blog(parent = blog_key(), subject=subject, content=content)
            a.put() 
            self.redirect("/blog/%s" %str(a.key().id()))
        else:
            error = "we need both a subject and some text!"
            self.render_newpost(subject, content, error)
```

I use this piece of code to define a key:

```
def blog_key(name = 'default'):
    return db.Key.from_path('blogs', name)
```

My problem is when trying to render it, the following using get_by_id works:

```
class PermalinkHandler(Handler):
    def get(self, blog_id):
        blog = Blog.get_by_id(int(blog_id), parent=None)
    if not blog:
         self.response.write('There is no blog whose id is %s' %blog_id)
         return
        self.render("permalink.html", blog = blog)
```

When I try to replace `blog = Blog.get_by_id(int(blog_id), parent=None)` with

```
k = db.Key.from_path('Blog', int(blog_id), parent=blog_key())
blog = db.get(k)
```

It doesn't work, any idea why?
Thx

Comment: Two suggestions: Use webap2, NDB and use a default_value when you use self.request.get('subscribe', default_value=None)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious question is are you supplying the parent in the working code.

```
def get(self, blog_id):
        blog = Blog.get_by_id(int(blog_id), parent=None)
```

Looking at your code the parent is always None, and in your post handler you are not showing us how you create blog_key

Then in your non working code you have

```
k = db.Key.from_path('Blog', int(blog_id), parent=blog_key())
blog = db.get(k)
```

So my guess is the problem is due to inconsistent use of parent  in your keys.

Comment: I'm little bit confused because seems the entity creation is done using a parent key.

Comment: @TimHoffman I do show you how blog_key() is created, it's in the following code: def blog_key(name = 'default'):
    return db.Key.from_path('blogs', name)

Comment: OK missed that,so there is a clear discrepancy between how you are retrieving in your PermalinkHandler as it doesn't appear to be  setting the parent anywhere I can see. However you claim you are setting the parent in your post handler. Have you fetched some keys for Blog entities and examined the Keys to see if they have parents.  get_by_id can not work if the entities have parents and you don't supply them.

Comment: Originally in NewPostHandler, the line of code which reads 'a = Blog(parent = blog_key(), subject=subject, content=content)' didn't include 'parent = blog_key()' that's why PermalinkHandler included 'blog = Blog.get_by_id(int(blog_id), parent=None)'. I try now to replace the original which didn't include blog_key() to the one which does and so i try to understand what's the equivalent of get_by_id which uses key.from_path. Hope this is clear?!

Comment: Actually replacing:'blog = Blog.get_by_id(int(blog_id), parent=None)' with 'blog = Blog.get_by_id(int(blog_id), parent=blog_key())' works, but my issue is trying to understand key.from_path

Comment: Get by id is just a shortcut ultimately you need to construct a matching key, which involves a parent and an id and type.  You are just running to some inconsistancies in your use. have a read of the docs  on the structure of keys,